How can I Integrate Twilio with its api.sendgrid.com with Genexus X Ev3?
I try to consume a Twilio service to send mail by using its API (api.sendgrid.com) but I can't determine why it is not working for me, I already validated with a SOAP & REST Client and here it works perfectly, I am using GeneXus X ev3 upg 15 with C# on the Web.
Some code example?

Follow the instructions in the official doc, for sending with API:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/sendgrid/for-developers/sending-email/api-getting-started

Use the &HttpClient variable in Genexus to build your request.
Plus: Change the property "Log Level=6.All" at generator level, this will help you understand what is happening.
Another way is to use SMTP API, as follows in the SendGrid doc:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/sendgrid/for-developers/sending-email/integrating-with-the-smtp-api
Genexus SMTP: https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/wiki?6937,SMTPSession+Data+Type

